# How to enable decorators in NodeJs lambda function that are built and deployed using AWS CDK?

Tags: node.js, aws-cdk, tsc, typescript-decorator, esbuild

I have refactored my lambda function by applying DI principles using the [tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe) library. Unfortunately, after my lamdas are built to the cloud, services have not been injected properly and dependencies are undefined.
The issue is probably connected to esBuild because I could replicate this issue locally if I used it for code compilation. If I compile this code locally using TSC this issue does not occur and dependencies are properly injected.
How can I tinker the build process so I can still use AWS CDK and dependencies will be injected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like tsyringe requires the emitDecoratorMetadata option, which [isn't supported natively by esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/257).

You have a couple of options to make it work:

1. Set the [preCompilation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.BundlingOptions.html#precompilation) option to true. This will run your build with tsc instead of esbuild. It'll be a bit slower, but you'll be able to emit the decorators.
2. Use a plugin like [esbuild-plugin-tsc](https://github.com/thomaschaaf/esbuild-plugin-tsc).

For Lambda, option #1 here is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you this should serve my needs. Have a great day! :)

Comment: @JurajZovinec did you manage to get it to work with the preCompilation flag? I'm currently struggling with it. Do you perhaps have a small demo repo I can have a look at? It seems as the preCompilation messes up my rootDir setting in my Lambda's tsconfig.json.